# Remove duplicate rows from csv file without writing a new file

Tags: java, csv, hashset

This is my code for now:

```
File file1 = new File("file1.csv");
File file2 = new File("file2.csv");
HashSet<String> f1 = new HashSet<>(FileUtils.readLines(file1));
HashSet<String> f2 = new HashSet<>(FileUtils.readLines(file2));
f2.removeAll(f1);
```

With `removeAll()` I remove all duplicates which are in file2 from file1, but now I want to avoid to create a new csv file to optimize the process. Just want to delete from file2 the duplicate rows.

Is this possible or do I have to create a new file?

Comment: Is there any chance to implementing of database for above task?

Comment: Caan't you just store f2 result back to file?

Comment: It's not that you don't want to write the whole file to disk (random access files would be no option here, I think) but that you have two files but only want / need one, right?

Comment: Yes, I need just one file because it is the most recent. So, this one doesn't need old records that were yet stored in the database, but only the new ones.
This function returns a boolean, so I don't know how to assign back to file2.

Comment: Ah ok I think now I get it. File1 is created and holds some data which is then processed. Later File2 is created which also contains the data from File1. While processing File2 you don't want to process the data which was already processed in file on again. So after your code you have the actually needed data in f2. So the last step would just be to write the content of f2 back to file2.

Comment: Ok I've solved with an quick overwrite with this:
FileUtils.writeLines(file2, f2);
I don't know is there a more efficient solution for very large data, but this can be fine for a small-medium file.

Comment: Looks fine. And you actually don't have another option for large files. You don't know where in the file your data is removed and imaging that a few lines in the middle of the file would be removed you would still need to move the later lines a bit to the beginning of the file to close the gap. So a rewrite of the file is the only useful way. With large files the IO speed would be the minor problem anyways. Loading like two 500MB files in your memory would be the bigger problem.

Answer (score 2):

> now I want to avoid to create a new csv file to optimize the process.

Well, sure, you can do that... If you don't mind possibly losing the file!

**DON'T DO THAT**.

And since you use Java 7, well, [use java.nio.file](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API). Here's an example:

```
final Path file1 = Paths.get("file1.csv");
final Path file2 = Paths.get("file2.csv");
final Path tmpfile = file2.resolveSibling("file2.csv.new");

final Set<String> file1Lines 
    = new HashSet<>(Files.readAllLines(file1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

try (
    final BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file2,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tmpfile,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if (!file1Lines.contains(line)) {
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
}

try {
    Files.move(tmpfile, file2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
        StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
} catch (AtomicMoveNotSupportedException ignored) {
    Files.move(tmpfile, file2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

If you use Java 8, you can use this try-with-resources block instead:

```
try (
    final Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tmpfile,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
) {
    stream.filter(line -> !file1Lines.contains(line))
        .forEach(line -> { writer.write(line); writer.newLine(); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this line of code:

```
FileUtils.writeLines(file2, f2);
```

It is an overwrite and can be a good solution for small-medium file,
but for very large dataset I sincerly don't know.

Comment: You could use the return of removeAll to see if writing the new file is neccessary. `returns true if this set changed as a result of the call`